# Question about Lemma1.1 to prove Bloch's Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

**1.1 Lemma** Le $f$ be an analytic in $D=D(0,1)$ and suppose that $f(0)=0$, $f'(0)=1$, and $\vert f(z)\vert \leq M$ for all $z$ in $D$. Then $M\geq 1$ and $f(D)\supset B(0, 1/6M)$.

*Proof.* Let $0<r<1$ and $f(z) = z + a_{2}z^{2}+ \ldots$; according to Cauchy's Estimate $\vert a_{n} \vert \leq M/r^{n}$. So $1=a_{1}\leq M$. If $\vert z\vert =(4M)^{-1}$ then

\begin{align*}
\vert f(z)\vert &\geq \vert z\vert - \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\vert a_{n}z^{n}\vert\\
&\geq (4M)^{-1} - \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} M(4M)^{-n}.
\end{align*}

Why is $a_{1}\leq M$ ? The inequality give $a_{1}\leq M/r$ ...

Second, why is it $M$ in the sum ?

Comment: Lemma 1.1 where?

Comment: Functions of One Complexe Variable (Second Edition) from John B. Conway

Answer (score 1):

$|a_n| \leq M/r^{n}$ for every $r \in (0,1)$. Letting $r$ increase to $1$ we get $|a_n| \leq M$.